# query to array show all values 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, prepared-statement

I want to put the query into an array, but I'm having troubles with the array.
This is my code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("
    SELECT id, sentence, form
    FROM exercises
    ORDER BY rand()
    LIMIT 1
");
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
var_dump($data);
```

which outputs:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "6" [0]=> string(1) "6" ["sentence"]=> string(18) "This is a sentence" [1]=> string(18) "This is a sentence" ["form"]=> string(5) "Form3" [2]=> string(5) "Form3" 
    } 
}
```

But I want the array to be like this:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["sentence"]=> string(18) "This is a sentence"  ["form"]=> string(5) "Form3" 
    } 
}
```

Can someone tell me why every value is shown 2 times??

Comment: Use `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to get an associative array instead of both numbered and named elements.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this anywhere and have been searching for quite a while!

Comment: Did you try the documentation of [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)? **PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values are shown 2 times because the default fetch style option for PDOStatement::fetch is PDO::FETCH_BOTH, which returns an array indexed by both numbers and column names.

If you want to get only column names, use  `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

You can find more information in the PHP manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php